# mobile sliding menu is not showing up

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, menu

I ran into a problem. I've been trying to implement this "hamburger" mobile sliding menu into my website. The javascript is working, but the menu is not showing.

Anyone know of this? http://www.ymc.ch/en/how-to-make-a-hamburger-a-menu-for-mobile-websites

I've made my css and HTML code a bit different, but the jQuery is the same.

I've looked through this and I figured it might be a css conflict but I don't know what exactly. I have another stylesheet that uses .container, but I also don't know if that's the reason.

Here's my link: http://thestripedphoenix.com/
I wanted my website to be responsive while having the hamburger menu tool.

Please, help. I've spent days on this, and I don't think I'd be able to do this alone.

Thanks!!!!!

My HTML markup is here (index.html)

```
<!-- Mobile Page Layout
================================================== -->

<!--This wrapping container is used to get the width of the whole content-->

<div id="container">

    <!--The Hamburger Button in the Header-->
    <header>
        <div id="logo"><img src="images/tsp+design-header-mobile.png" width="271" height="78"/>
        </div>
            <div id="hamburger">
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </div>
    </header>

    <!--The mobile navigation Markup hidden via css-->
    <nav class="mobileNav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">about</a></li>
            <li><a href="portfolio-photo.html">photography</a></li>
            <li><a href="portfolio-illustration.html">illustration</a></li>
            <li><a href="portfolio-animation.html">animation</a></li>
            <li><a href="portfolio-web-design.html">web design</a></li>
            <li><a href="resume.html">resume</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <!--The Layer that will be layed over the content
    so that the content is unclickable while menu is shown-->
    <div id="contentLayer"></div>


<!-- Primary Page Layout
================================================== -->
<div id="content">

<div class="container">
    <div class="six columns">
        <div id="header"><a href="index.html"><img src="images/tsp+design-header.png"/></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="two columns" id="navigation">
        <nav id="d-nav">
            <dl>
                <dt id="about"><a href="about.html">about</a></dt>
                <dt id="portfolio"><a href="portfolio.html">portfolio</a></dt>
                <dt id="resume"><a href="resume.html">resume</a></dt>
                <dt id="contact"><a href="contact.html">contact</a></dt>
            </dl>
        </nav>
    </div>

    <div id="space">
    </div>

        <div class="eight columns">
            <div class="slider-wrapper">
                <div id="slider1" class="nivoSlider theme-default">
                    <img src="images/gallery/image2-cropped.jpg"/>
                    <img src="images/gallery/image3-cropped.jpg"/>
                    <img src="images/gallery/image4-cropped.jpg"/>
                    <img src="images/gallery/image5-cropped.jpg"/>
                    <img src="images/gallery/image7-cropped.jpg"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="eight columns">
            <div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
                <div id="slider2" class="nivoSlider">
                    <img src="images/gallery/image8-cropped.png"/>
                    <img src="images/gallery/image10-cropped.png"/>
                    <img src="images/gallery/image12-cropped.png"/>
                    <img src="images/gallery/image13-cropped.png"/>
                    <img src="images/gallery/image15-cropped.png"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="eight columns">
            <div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
                <div id="slider3" class="nivoSlider">
                    <img src="images/gallery/image18-cropped.png"/>
                    <img src="images/gallery/image19-cropped.png"/>
                    <img src="images/gallery/image20-cropped.png"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="eight columns">
            <div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
                <div id="slider4" class="nivoSlider">
                    <img src="images/gallery/image21-cropped.png"/>
                    <img src="images/gallery/image22-cropped.png"/>
                    <img src="images/gallery/image24-cropped.png"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
                <div id="slider5" class="nivoSlider">

                    <img src="images/gallery/image2-cropped.jpg"/>
                    <img src="images/gallery/image3-cropped.jpg"/>
                    <img src="images/gallery/image4-cropped.jpg"/>
                    <img src="images/gallery/image5-cropped.jpg"/>
                    <img src="images/gallery/image7-cropped.jpg"/>
                    <img src="images/gallery/image8-cropped.png"/>
                    <img src="images/gallery/image10-cropped.png"/>
                    <img src="images/gallery/image12-cropped.png"/>
                    <img src="images/gallery/image13-cropped.png"/>
                    <img src="images/gallery/image15-cropped.png"/>
                    <img src="images/gallery/image18-cropped.png"/>
                    <img src="images/gallery/image19-cropped.png"/>
                    <img src="images/gallery/image20-cropped.png"/>
                    <img src="images/gallery/image21-cropped.png"/>
                    <img src="images/gallery/image22-cropped.png"/>
                    <img src="images/gallery/image24-cropped.png"/>

                </div>
            </div>

        <div id="space">
        </div>

        <div id="footer">
            <img src="images/footer-line.png" width="960" height="25"></a>
            <a href="about.html">about</a><span>|</span><a href="portfolio.html">portfolio</a><span>|</span><a href="resume.html">resume</a><span>|</span><a href="contact.html">contact</a>
            <p></p>
        </div>
        <div id="social">
            <a href="https://www.behance.net/thestripedphoenix"><img src="images/behance-icon.png" width="30" height="30"></a></a><a href="https://dribbble.com/thestripedphoenix"><img src="images/dribbble-icon.png" width="30" height="30"></a></a><a href="http://www.linkedin.com/pub/michelle-shean/65/407/129"><img src="images/linkedin-icon.png" width="30" height="30"></a></a><a href="http://www.youtube.com/user/mps3545"><img src="images/youtube-icon.png" width="30" height="30"></a></a><a href="#"><img src="images/zazzle-icon.png" width="30" height="30"></a></a>
        </div>
        <div id="copyright">
            <p>Copyright Michelle Shean, 2014</p>
        </div>

</div><!-- .container-->

</div><!-- content -->
```

Part of my CSS (for mobile size)

```
/* Mobile Landscape Size to Tablet Portrait (devices and browsers) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) {

/*
Setup a basic body
*/
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow-x: hidden;
font-family: Helvetica; Arial; sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
}

/*
Header is relative so z-index: 1 guarantees always displayed on top
*/
header {
background-color: #000000;
padding: 10px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
text-decoration: none;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
z-index: 1;
-webkit-box-shadow:  0px 3px 7px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
box-shadow:  0px 3px 7px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

#logo {
display: inline;
}

/*
using background color is important to cover the menu
position absolute isset to cover the whole viewport
*/
#content {
background-color: #000000;
font-family:  'league_gothicregular'; Helvetica; Arial; Sans-serif;
padding: 52px 10px 10px 10px;
position: relative;
max-width: 480px;
height: auto;
overflow-x: hidden;
-webkit-box-shadow:  -10px 0px 9px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
box-shadow:  -10px 0px 9px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

/*
the hamburger button with a little gradient effekt
*/
#hamburger {
border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
cursor: pointer;
display: block;
float: right;
margin-right: 50px;
margin-top: 23px;
height: 24px;
padding: 3px 4px 3px;
position: relative;
width: 25px;
background: #4569b2;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #000000 0%, #000000 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#000000)color-      stop(100%,#000000));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #000000 0%,#000000 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #000000 0%,#000000 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #000000 0%,#000000 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #000000 0%,#000000 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#000000', endColorstr='#000000',GradientType=0 );
}

/*
The white stripes in the hamburger button
*/
#hamburger div {
background-color: #fff;
border: 1px solid #eee;
border-radius: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
height: 2px;
margin-top: 3px;
width: 90%;
}

/*
The navigation container in the background
*/
nav {
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
position: fixed;
z-index: 0;
width: 70%;
height: 100%;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
overflow-x:hidden;
overflow-y:auto ;
background: #3e3c3d;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #3e3c3d 0%, #2d2c2d 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#3e3c3d), color-stop(100%,#2d2c2d));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #3e3c3d 0%,#2d2c2d 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #3e3c3d 0%,#2d2c2d 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #3e3c3d 0%,#2d2c2d 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #3e3c3d 0%,#2d2c2d 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#3e3c3d', endColorstr='#2d2c2d',GradientType=0 );
}

/*
Style the navigation menu
*/
nav ul {
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
width: 100%;
padding: 0;
}

nav li {
position: relative;
font-size: 1em;
font-weight: bold;
border-bottom: 1px solid #222222;
border-top: 1px solid #444444;
padding: 15px;
}
nav li a {
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
}

/*
The Layer that will be layed over the content
so that the content is unclickable while menu is shown
*/
#contentLayer {
display: none;
height: 100%;
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: auto;
position: absolute;
right: 0;
top: 0;
width: 30%;
z-index: 5;
min-height: 1062px;
}

#header {
display: none;
}

#logo {
display: inline;
}

#slider1 {
display: none;
position: relative;
width: auto;
float: left;
clear: both;
margin-top: 50px;
margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#slider2 {
display: none;
position: relative;
width: auto;
float: left;
clear: both;
margin-top: 50px;
}

#slider3 {
display: none;
position: relative;
width: auto;
float: left;
clear: both;
}

#slider4 {
display: none;
position: relative;
width: auto;
float: left;
clear: both;
}

#slider5 {
display: inline;
position: relative;
width: auto;
float: left;
clear: both;
}

#about-pic {
position: relative;
margin-left: 10px;
margin-top: 10px;
min-width: 220px;
max-width: 220px;
float: left;
}

#section-title-blue {
position: relative;
clear: both;
margin-left: 10px;
width: 800px;
min-width: 480px;
height: 60px;
float: left;
font-size: 2em;
color: #00CBD4;
}

#section-title-green {
position: relative;
clear: both;
margin-top: 5px;
margin-left: 10px;
width: 800px;
min-width: 480px;
height: 60px;
float: left;
font-size: 2em;
color: #2AFF38;
}

#about-pic img {
width: 100%;
}

#about-text {
position: relative;
margin-top: 30px;
float: right;
width: 100%;
font-size: 1.1em;
font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Sans-serif;
}

#signature {
font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Sans-serif;
float: left;
margin-top: 40px;
max-width: 120px;
max-height: 120px;
}

#portfolio-gallery {
display: none;
}

#portfolio-nav {
display: none;
}

#mobile-gallery {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
margin-top: 50px;
clear: both;
padding: 20px;
padding-right: 30px;
padding-top: 10px
max-width: 480px;
max-height: 720px;
}

#mobile-gallery img {
width: auto;
}

/* line 180, ../sass/screen.sass */
.image-row {
 *zoom: 1;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 }
 /* line 38, ../../../../.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/compass-0.12.2/frameworks/compass     /stylesheets/compass/utilities/general/_clearfix.scss */
 .image-row:after {
 content: "";
 display: table;
 clear: both;
}

/* line 184, ../sass/screen.sass */
.example-image-link {
display: inline-block;
margin: 0 10px 20px 10px;
line-height: 0;
-webkit-border-radius: 4px;
-moz-border-radius: 4px;
-ms-border-radius: 4px;
-o-border-radius: 4px;
border-radius: 4px;
border: 2px solid #5e5e5e;
-webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
-o-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
}
/* line 191, ../sass/screen.sass */
.example-image-link:hover {
 border: 2px solid #2AFF38;
}

/* line 194, ../sass/screen.sass */
.example-image {
-webkit-border-radius: 2px;
-moz-border-radius: 2px;
-ms-border-radius: 2px;
-o-border-radius: 2px;
border-radius: 2px;
}

#subheading {
position: relative;
clear: both;
max-width: 360px;
min-width: 430px;
height: 40px;
margin-top: 20px;
margin-left: 10px;
float: left;
font-size: 1.5em;
}

#resume-text {
position: relative;
max-width: 360px;
max-height: 130px;
margin-top: 20px;
margin-left: 10px;
float: left;
font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Sans-serif;
}

#resume-note {
position: relative;
clear: both;
float: left;
margin-left: 70px;
margin-top: 30px;
margin-bottom: 30px;
width: 600px;
height: 30px;
font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Sans-serif;
font-size: 1.2em;
}

#resume-note {
position: relative;
clear: both;
float: left;
margin-left: 10px;
margin-top: 30px;
margin-bottom: 30px;
width: 600px;
height: 30px;
font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Sans-serif;
font-size: 1em;
}

#form {
position: relative;
max-width: 450px;
min-width: 460px;
height: 820px;
margin-top: 20px;
margin-left: 10px;
margin-bottom: 40px;
float: left;
clear: both;
font-size: 1.2em;
padding: 20px;
border: none;
}

input, textarea {
padding: 5px;
margin: 10px;
font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Sans-serif;
font-size: medium;
font-weight: bold;
outline: none;
}

input[type=text], textarea {
width: 220px;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

input[type=submit] {
width: 100px;
background-color: #2AFF38;
border: 1px solid #000000;
font-size: large;
color: #FFFFFF;
margin-bottom: 30px;
}

input[submit]:active {
background-color: #00CBD4;
}

h1 {
font-family: 'league_gothicregular', Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 2.1em;
}

#footer {
position: relative;
margin-top: 10px;
max-width: 960px;
max-height: 80px;
float: left;
text-align: center;
font-size: 1.5em;
}

#footer img {
width: 100%;
}

#social {
position: relative;
clear: both;
max-width: 200px;
height: 40px;
margin: auto;
padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#social img {
margin: 5px;
display: inline-block;
}

#copyright {
position: relative;
clear: both;
text-align: center;
margin: auto;
min-width: 30px;
padding-bottom: 15px;
font-size: 1.2em;
}

a:link {
color: #FFFFFF;
}

a:active {
color: #FFFFFF;
}

a:visited {
color: #FFFFFF;
}

span {
margin: 5px;
}

}
```

Here is the head of my HTML markup:

```
    <head>

    <!-- Basic Page Needs
  ================================================== -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>the striped phoenix | Michelle Shean</title>
    <meta name="description" content="portfolio">
    <meta name="author" content="portfolio">
    <body oncontextmenu="return false;">

    <!-- Mobile Specific Metas
  ================================================== -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale = 1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />

    <!--Using jQuery and jQuery UI for display effects
  ================================================== -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <!--Using the hamburger menu display code
   =================================================== -->
    <script src="javascripts/hamburger.js"></script>

    <!-- CSS
  ================================================== -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/base.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/skeleton.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/layout.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/nivo-slider.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/slider-themes/default/default.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />


    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Favicons
    ================================================== -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="images/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="images/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


</head>
```

The jQuery code is the same as from your demo.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    //Open the menu
    jQuery("#hamburger").click(function() {

        //set the width of primary content container -> content should not scale while animating
        var contentWidth = jQuery('#content').width();

        //set the content with the width that it has originally
        jQuery('#content').css('width', contentWidth);

        //display a layer to disable clicking and scrolling on the content while menu is shown
        jQuery('#contentLayer').css('display', 'block');

        //disable all scrolling on mobile devices while menu is shown
        jQuery('#container').bind('touchmove', function(e){e.preventDefault()});

        //set margin for the whole container with a jquery UI animation
        jQuery("#container").animate({"marginLeft": ["70%", 'easeOutExpo']}, {
            duration: 700
        });

    });

    //close the menu
    jQuery("#contentLayer").click(function() {

        //enable all scrolling on mobile devices when menu is closed
        jQuery('#container').unbind('touchmove');

        //set margin for the whole container back to original state with a jquery UI animation
        jQuery("#container").animate({"marginLeft": ["0", 'easeOutExpo']}, {
            duration: 700,
            complete: function() {
                  jQuery('#content').css('width', 'auto');
                jQuery('#contentLayer').css('display', 'none');

            }
        });
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

did you use the jQuery part for this like the onclick animation to show the menu.

### please see here:

`demo`
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lokeshpahal/3k4VH/1/)

Comment: I can see it is working in the link you provided. I had the jQuery script tag placed in the head of the HTML, according to the instructions provided by the creator.

Do you think I should put in the entire jQuery code in the bottom of the HTML markup?

Comment: Yes its the same code as in demo, I can see that you have included jQuery two different version files, please try by removing `jQuery 1.7.2`.

Comment: It works!! Just one more question. When the content slides to the right, it is still scrollable. How do you disable vertical scrolling of the content while the mobile menu is open?

Comment: Just user overflow hidden using jQuery CSS method `$.CSS({overflow:'hiddden'})` for content DIV when mobile menu is opened apply `$.css({overflow:'auto'})` after hidden.

Comment: I'm not sure if I put it in correctly. Where specifically in the jQuery code should I put in? I'm new to javascript, so please bear with me.

Comment: here is the code part mentioned in comment where you have to put code:`jQuery("#container").animate({"marginLeft": ["70%", 'easeOutExpo']}, {
  duration: 700,
  complete: function() {
    // code to make overflow hidden
  }
});

jQuery("#container").animate({"marginLeft": ["0", 'easeOutExpo']}, {
  duration: 700,
  complete: function() {
      jQuery('#content').css('width', 'auto');
      jQuery('#contentLayer').css('display', 'none');
      // code here to make overflow auto
  }
});`

Comment: I put in the code as you said. It still scrolls. :/ See http://jsfiddle.net/3k4VH/2/

Comment: I can see that the scrolling is due to the jsfiddle Iframe you can inspect with firebug. It should work fine on your webpage.

Comment: So, I've been doing some coding with jQuery and realized that I only had to put in 'body' in place of 'content'. Now, it's working. Thanks for helping!

Comment: hmmm, its ok, pleasure to help you out :)